# Using GET and POST in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some trouble posting data through AJAX. I created a small save script which determines in which table a POST must be saved (I am using a different form for each table):

```
$(function() 
{
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({ axis: "x" });
});

function save(target)
{
    switch(target)
    {
        case "praktijk":
            $.ajax({                                                                                                           url: 'webscripts/admin/opslaan.php?type=praktijk',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#tabs-2").find('form').serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    alert("gegevens opgeslagen!");
                    $('#popup').dialog('close');
                }
            });
            break;
        case "persoonlijk":
            $.ajax({                                                                                   
                url: 'webscripts/admin/opslaan.php?type=persoonlijk',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#tabs-1").find('form').serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    alert("gegevens opgeslagen!");
                    $('#popup').dialog('close');
            }
        });
        break;
    case "vragen":
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webscripts/admin/opslaan.php?type=vragen',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#tabs-3').find('form').serialize(),
            success: function(){
                    alert("gegevens opgeslagen!");
                    $('#popup').dialog('close');
            }
        });
        break;
}
```

}

as you can see, I next determine it for the PHP script by using a GET variable that says which table it needs to save it in. But this doesn't work. The script appears to be crashing at this point. I am not sure where exactly it crashes.. the Firebug terminal doesn't show any obvious errors.

Does somebody know why it doesn't work?

Comment: do you mean to say you are not getting "type" in opslaan.php ?

Comment: how you are calling the save function???

Comment: I am calling it via a button with an onClick event. So for example I do this for the persoonlijk (personal) table: <button onClick='opslaan("persoonlijk")' />

Comment: you don't need javascript at all... change the button to `<button type="submit">opslaan</button>` and let your php script do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're using a different form for each table, why not send the right table name ('persoonlijk', 'vragen', etc.) with the form itself?

example:

```
<form ...>
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="persoonlijk" />
...
</form>
```

And in php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['target'] == 'persoonlijk') {
    // save in table 'persoonlijk'
} else {
   // save it somewhere else
}
?>
```

Furthermore, reading out a php var can not break your javascript, simply because you are working on the server, and javascript works in the browser. Please print out the get en post vars using `print_r($_GET);`, then explain what 'seems to break' means (what happens, what do you see (error messages and such)).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I added the input type hidden in the POST values and removed that GET parameter altogether. I tried to add the print_r but that doesn't show up.. in the firebug console the line turns red as soon as I click the save button, so that's why I think it crashes somehow

Comment: Please be more precise with your replies. Which line turned red in the console? Is there an error message in the console, and what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

`data:`should contain some data. It should be a text or value and your code doesn't seems to have it correctly set up. I recommend you to use some `var` there.

Comment: The post is constructed the right way. Firebug shows that the POST data is at least contains the right value.